# M2: flushing cache lets page render one time, then blank white page thereafter

Tags: magento2, cache

I'm working through Alan Storm's 'No Frills Magento 2 Layout' an internal dev server. He walks the reader through small edit, refresh, another small edit, refresh, see what changes, and so on. There are lots of examples. Then I inserted a typo which I couldn't find, that ended up being whitespace added at the end of `'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template '` when I copied and paste from the PDF manual.

I then sorted out getting errors enabled, however **I managed to get the Magento 2.3.2 install into a bad state where there are white pages on every refresh.** Clean the cache and hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, the site comes back, but for only one render.

This was a fresh install and I had only executed `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` as per the install instructions for the module which is part of the book.

I then started an exploration of every command available from the internet in an attempt to be able to hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and just get a page to reload. I issued these two commands:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento cache:disable
```

And now the site will refresh with <kbd>F5</kbd> but instead of quickly refreshing, the server grinds for 7 to 10 seconds and then renders `Hello World`

**What mechanism in Magento 2 causes this?**
and
**What can a person do to get back to how the site was working as expected before all this?**

Right now, I believe the solution is to move this M2 and start over by installing a new fresh instance. But that simply is not acceptable; what happens if a live site starts acting like this? Having to clean cache to render one page is not acceptable nor is disabling cache...

Comment: Did a fresh install and this new fresh install fails to render once I get to "Template Blocks" on page 18 of his book. On the former fresh install, I was able to do these steps and it all went sideways on the Layout section.

Answer (score 0):

While it does not fully explain some inconsistencies from my experience leading to the initial question, I have since learned a few things which help explain what happened above.

**1. There was a typo I didn't notice.** I fell victim to the "didn't have the '`/`' where it belongs" and it caused an error. Because I did get errors to show up, the output helped me find the problem. On page 20 of Alan's book, the same code is shown twice:
`class Template extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` and later on as:
`class Template extends Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`
I didn't notice the typo on the second copy of the "same code" and it got me; an expected Magento-kind of coding error. *(I did let the author know)*

**2. Mentioning "cache:clean" was not soon enough.** The book begins the mantra of "clean cache and refresh the page" once `XML` layouts are introduced. <kbd>F5</kbd> works with Controller and Block changes, however when a layout or the blocks instantiated via `$layout` variable are changed, <kbd>F5</kbd> produces an empty, white, blank page. We might all know you need to clean the cache all the time, but having read the chapter before trying it, I observed the "clean cache and refresh" and didn't think to begin obeying that earlier than the repetitive chant said we must obey.

**3. "Blank" or white pages give no feedback.** Even with errors reporting correctly, there's no indicator from Magento that it served a blank page because cache needs to be cleaned. No indicator means no errors logged for the webserver or in magento's `var/log`.